# Order of watching Spider-Man movies

Tags: marvel, movie, suggested-order, spider-man

What is the order for watching the Spider-Man movies? I tried finding it online, but it included all the "failed projects" and animated TV shows.  Could someone please make a list of the (live-action) Spider-Man movies and what order to watch them in?

Comment: One question per question please, if you want an answer to the other one you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't simply watch them in order of realease?

Comment: If two or more Spider-Man movies are in a series, they should be watched in order of release (unless they include prequels), but otherwise different Spider-Man movies that are in different continuities can be watched in any old order.  It is theoretically possible for two Spider-Man movie series to overlapp in release dates.  And what about movies without Spider-Man that are in continuity with Spider-Man movies? There was also a live action Spider-Man TV series whose episodes could be watched in production or in broadcast order.

Comment: I couldn't find a comprehensive list of order of release, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best order to watch the Spider-Man movies in release order that would make the most sense.

1. Spider-Man (1977)  -A made-for-TV pilot movie for the live-action series The Amazing Spider-Man, starring Nicholas Hammond.
2. Spider-Man Strikes Back (1978) - Initially a 2-part episode entitled "Deadly Dust", was eventually re-released as "Spider-Man Strikes Back". It is the second of three Amazing Spider-Man (Nicholas Hammond, not Andrew Garfield) movies.
3. Spider-Man: The Dragon's Challenge_ (1981) - The third and final of the Amazing Spider-Man TV movies, it was also initially a 2-part episode of the TV series that was re-released as a film. It is the last of the Amazing Spider-Man movies.
4. Spider-Man (1978) - A TV film made as a spinoff of the Japanese Spider-Man show (Sometimes referred to as Supaidaman), it takes place between episodes 10 ( To the Flaming Hell: See the Tears of the Snake Woman) and 11 (Professor Monster's Ultra Poisoning).
5. Spider-Man (2002) - The first of the Sam Raimi/Tobey Maguire Spider-Man trilogy, stars Willem Dafoe as Norman Osborn/The Green Goblin, Rosemary Harris as Aunt May, Cliff Robertson as Uncle Ben, James Franco as Harry Osborn, Kirsten Dunst as Mary Jane 'MJ' Watson, and J.K. Simmons as J. Jonah Jameson.
6. Spider-Man 2 (2004) - Set two years after Spider-Man (2002), adapts the storyline "Spider-Man No More!" and has the entire original cast return, along with adding Alfred Molina as Dr. Otto Octavius, who eventually becomes Doctor Octopus/Doc Ock. Uncle Ben and Norman Osborn even cameo.
7. Spider-Man 3 (2007) - The third and final Sam Raimi Spider-Man movie, this film brought in Thomas Haden Church to play Flint Marko/Sandman, Topher Grace to play Eddie Brock/Venom, Bryce Dallas Howard for a small, but interesting role as Gwen Stacy, and finally had Harry Osborn take on his father's persona of the Green Goblin, being referred to in advertising and merchandise as 'New Goblin', despite never once being called that on film.
8. Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse (2018)-Debated where to put this for quite some time, but the Amazing version of Spider-Man (Peter B. Parker) that mentors and helps Miles Morales seems to have some very similar ties to Tobey Maguire's Spidey.
9. The Amazing Spider-Man (2012) - After 5 years of no Spider-Man movies, Sony decided they were ready to make another, but decided a reboot was best due to how Spider-Man 3 was received. This film places Peter Parker and Gwen Stacy in a high-school setting where Peter gets bitten by a radioactive spider and inadvertently helps Dr. Curtis Connors (Rhys Ifans) become The Lizard. Sally Fields and Martin Sheen play Aunt May and Uncle Ben respectively, and this is the first Spider-Man film to talk about Peter's parents in depth.
10. The Amazing Spider-Man 2 (2014) - Released in some places as The Amazing Spider-Man 2: Rise of Electro, this movie introduces Jamie Foxx as Max Dillon, who eventually becomes Electro, Dane DeHann as Harry Osborn and his eventual transformation into the Green Goblin, and Paul Giammatti as Aleksei Sytsevich. The film handles "The Death of Gwen Stacy" storyline from the comics and tried to set up a Sinister Six solo film, but failed.
11. Captain America: Civil War (2016) - On the list largely as a technicality, this film introduced audiences to Chadwick Boseman as T'Challa/The Black Panther and Tom Holland as Peter Parker/Spider-Man. Peter's role in this movie is he is recruited by Iron Man to apprehend Captain America during one of the coolest MCU battles to date.
12. Spider-Man: Homecoming (2017) - Tom Holland's first solo Spider-Man film. In this movie, he faces off against Adrian Toomes/The Vulture, played fantastically by Michael Keaton. Although not necessary, if you have seen Marvel's The Avengers (2012), the opening of the movie deals a little bit with the Battle of New York from the end of that film.
13. Avengers: Infinity War (2018) - Although a relatively more active role in this film than in _Captain America: Civil War, it is still worth noting that Spider-Man is in this movie, he's just not the main star.
14. Avengers: Endgame (2019)-While this is largely a story about the Avengers undoing the events of Infinity War, Spider-Man does have an arc that has a pretty decent sized impact on Far From Home.
15. Spider-Man: Far From Home (2019)-Takes place almost immediately after Avengers: Endgame and largely deals with how Peter was affected by that movie and Infinity War, while also teaming up with Mysterio to fight the Elementals (largely based off of Sandman, Hydro-Man, and Molten Man to an extent).
16. Venom (2018)-While not connected to any of the main Spider-Man movies, this proves quite an enjoyable origin story if you're a fan of the character and has Riot as the villain, as well as a pretty nice part for Ann Weying (won't spoil what happens with her, but let's just say anyone who knows the comics well WON'T be disappointed).
17. Avengers: Endgame (2019)-While this is largely a story about the Avengers undoing the events of Infinity War, Spider-Man does have an arc that has a pretty decent sized impact on Far From Home.

Bonus Movie 1: Spider-Man 2.1 (2007) - An extended cut of Spider-Man 2, which contains 8 minutes of extra footage not in the original.

Bonus Movie 2: Spider-Man 3: Editor's Cut_ (2017) - An alternate cut of Spider-Man 3 with a few new scenes added and some old ones removed. Surprisingly, actually slightly better than the original Spider-Man 3.

One final thing: when watching the Raimi Trilogy, to get max enjoyment, I would suggest Spider-Man (2002) first, then Spider-Man 2.1, Spider-Man 3: Editor's Cut, and then top it off with Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse.

Comment: My pleasure. Just a heads-up, the three Nicholas Hammond films and the 1978 Supaidaman film do get a little cheesy. Still relatively decent, though.

Comment: @SophietheJediKnight-Hey, just wanted to check and see if you've had a chance to get started on the Spidey films yet, I personally always love a good old marathon viewing myself. Also, as a slight update to the list, Venom can be watched as completely separate to the Hammond, Raimi, Garfield, & MCU films

Comment: Thanks for the Venom notice!  My sister wanted to see that, and I was wondering.  No, not yet, my mom and sister and I are working our way through the MCU films.  Spiderman Homecoming is actually up next on that list.  After we get updated on that we'll probably start the Spider-Man movies.

Comment: No problem. Just as a heads-up, there are 2 post-credit scenes for every MCU movie from Spider-Man: Homecoming all the way to Ant-Man and the Wasp (the last MCU film until Captain Marvel next year); 1 during the mid-credits 1 at the end. This kind of applies to Venom, only the final credit scene is more or less a scene taken from the upcoming Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse movie.

Comment: Thanks!  We always fast-forward to the VERY end in a Marvel movie... you just never know...

Comment: Note: this is wonderful advice is you want to watch movies featuring Spider-Man. However, the 1970s set, the 2000s set (Spider-Man 1-3), and the early 2010s set (Amazing Spider-Man 1-2) are all unrelated - each may, in fact, include separate tellings of Spider-Man's origin. Since Spider-Man started appearing in the MCU (Captain America: Civil War), I'm not sure if he's supposed to be the same as any of the previous versions, or if *Homecoming* includes yet another telling of the origin.

Comment: New update: just found a parody film called Superhero Movie, and acts as a parody of comic book movies. Reason for bringing this up is the main focus is of a character played by Drake Bell who becomes a superhero known as The Dragonfly (parody of Spider-Man). This movie came out after the Raimi Trilogy, but before the Andrew Garfield films, by the way.